# PHP Replacing Array Value from Another Array

Tags: php

Can anyone lend me a suggestion on why my code below doesn't work? What I want to accomplish is `if $value1 == '0'` is true, then concatenate the value/text that correspond to the key order in `$stdArray2.` I'm not sure if this is the best or right way to do it. Is there a better way? The code seems clumpsy but can't complain much since my coding skill is pretty bad.

**My PHP**

```
$stdArray1 ['1']  = $orange;
$stdArray1 ['2']  = $apple;
$stdArray1 ['3']  = $peach;
$stdArray1 ['4']  = $berry;
$stdArray2 ['1']  = 'Flordia';
$stdArray2 ['2']  = 'Washington';
$stdArray2 ['3']  = 'Georgia';
$stdArray2 ['4']  = 'Oregon';

foreach($stdArray1 as $value1){
  if($value1 == '0'){
    foreach($stdArray2 as $value2){
      $fruit .= $value2', ';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want concatenate the corresponding second array value to first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the corresponding value in the second array, you shouldn't use a second loop, just use an array index.

```
foreach ($stdArray1 as $index => $value) {
    if ($value == '0') {
        $fruit .= $stdArray2[$index] . ", ";
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/qqQsRU)

Comment: Could you show the values of the variables `$orange`, `$apple`, `$peach`, and `$berry`? What is the result you were expecting to get?

Comment: My apologies Barmar. This works great. And the best way too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
foreach($stdArray1 as $value1){
  if($value1 == '0'){
    foreach($stdArray2 as $value2){
      $fruit .= $value2.', ';
    }
  }
}
```

You are missing `.` in foreach loop.

Comment: One period made my scratch my head so bad. Thank, Amit. This works.